# Application will not run on device: DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies

***Problem***:

I made some changes to my gradle file and whenever I try to run my application I keep getting the error `DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR` after being told that the application path must be uninstalled then re-installed to run the app. I approve the uninstall and then the `DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR` is thrown and execution just outright stops.

Here is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "benyamephrem.tilt"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 19
        versionName "3"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.0@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.0.8@aar'
}
```

Here is the ADB Logcat:

```
Installing benyamephrem.tilt
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/benyamephrem.tilt"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/benyamephrem.tilt
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]


DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm uninstall benyamephrem.tilt
DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR
```

I have installed all the sdk and build components needed as required by gradle. I also have uninstalled all apps with my package name from the device and the app still will not run.

***Question***:

What is `DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR` and why will the app not run?

Comment: Can you add your adb logcat?

Comment: @HarshDattani I have posted it.

Comment: are you trying in genymotion or any other such emulator. if yes try deleting the emulator and re creating the same

Comment: according  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38450717/session-app-error-while-installing-apk#answer-42617107 , try to disable 'instant run' . worked for me!

Answer (score 16):

Try cleaning the project in Android Studio and then building it again. To clean the project click on  **`Build > Clean Project`**.

I had the same issue and found this solution [here](http://www.mysysadmintips.com/windows/clients/574-can-t-deploy-apk-via-android-studio-stale-dexed-jars-install-failed-uid-changed).

Answer (score 2):

Open your project folder from command prompt and type: `gradlew clean`
it will initiate downloading once done restart your android studio and run your program.

Answer (score 1):

I followed all the method, but what worked was

1.open command prompt.

2.change directory to project folder.

3.write command

```
gradle clean
```

now try building !

Answer (score 1):

In my case there was a unknown package name in my manifest.xml

for example i forgot to change "YOURPACKAGENAME" string to my app package name

```
android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="YOURPACKAGENAME.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:** clean the project: Build > Clean Project.

**Solution 2:** Disable Instead Run

Steps for windows: File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run > Uncheck : Enable Instant Run

Steps for mac: Android Studio > Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run > Uncheck : Enable Instant Run

**Solution 3:** For Redmi users,

Go to Settings -> Permissions -> Install via USB: Uncheck your App if it's listed.

Go to Settings -> Additional Settings -> Privacy: Check the Unknown Sources option.

Go to Settings -> Additional Settings -> Developer options: Check the Install via USB option.

Go to Settings -> Additional Settings -> Developer options:Enable view attribute inspection

Finally, Go to Settings -> Additional Settings -> Developer options: Turn off MIUI optimization.

NOTE - Signin in to MI account is required to enable Install via USB option.

Reference: http://en.miui.com/thread-410773-1-1.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem ..

The problem was that I did not have enough space, I uninstall some applications and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If a Clean does not work,
make sure your minSdkVersion does not equal the target sdk version, and that the device you are testing with equals or is higher than the minSdkVersion.

Fixed it for me, example in build.gradle:

```
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 23
```

Answer (score 0):

I get this error almost after every **Run command** in the new Android Studio 2.2 Preview 6 version. To fix it faster instead of using **Clean Project** I'm using **Make project**. But this quick fix doesn't prevent the error from appearing again after a while.

Answer (score 0):

For Android Studio on Mac:

Navigation Bar:

Android Studio > Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run > Uncheck : Enable Instant Run

For Android Studio on Windows :

File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run > Uncheck : Enable Instant Run