# adb socket not working and daemon

Tags: android, sockets, adb, daemon, genymotion

I am getting this type of error

> error: could not install *smartsocket* listener: cannot bind to
>   127.0.0.1:5037: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (10048) 1:34:26
>   PM could not read ok from ADB Server 1:34:26 PM * failed to start
>   daemon * 1:34:26 PM error: cannot connect to daemon 1:34:26 PM
>   'C:\Users\MITESH
>   SUTHAR\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe,start-server'
>   failed -- run manually if necessary 1:38:14 PM Unable to obtain result
>   of 'adb version'

[my genymotion device is running but it shows me that no device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5ZNs.png)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I came across the same error. I provided the below command and the issue got solved.

**COMMAND :-** `taskkill /f /im adb.exe`

Comment: It says, "The process adb.exe is not found".

Comment: 'adb kill-server'
'adb start-server' these commands will help you

Answer (score 24):

1. Close Eclipse or Android Studio if either is running (Optional).
2. Open Command Prompt.
3. Go to the Android SDK `platform-tools` directory.
4. Type `adb kill-server`.
5. Type `adb start-server`.
6. If no error message is thrown while starting ADB server, then `adb` is started successfully.

OR

1. Go to Task Manager, open the Processes tab, and end the `adb.exe` process.
2. Then restart Android Studio.

This may work if there is any problem with adb.

Comment: Killing `adb.exe` is easiest option for Windows users

Answer (score 6):

In my case, none of the above solution worked. I solved it strangely maybe it can be a bug.

Do not run Genymotion emulator before Android Studio. Firstly, I opened android studio then I clicked run project and select deployment target windows appeared. Then I run genymotion emulator and now the emulator is shown in the select deployment target windows in Android Studio. Then deployed to the emulator without errors. Done!

As another way, you can try to set Genymotion sdk to the same as Android studio sdk. To do this, first find your sdk location. You can find it by right clicking the **Android Studio project -> Open Module Settings-> Select SDK location -> under Android SDK location**, it is shown. Then open **Genymotion ->  Settings -> ADB tab -> Click Use custom Android SDK tools radio button -> navigate to SDK folder used by Android studio -> Restart Genymotion virtual device**

Answer (score 1):

If none of the above worked for you, just make sure that you have closed Genymotion emulator as it caused this issue with me.

Answer (score 1):

**Easiest Way!** I just ran into this issue trying to connect a React-Native App to an Android Studio emulator. If you read the error message it tells you that ***"Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted."*** So you can assume that something other than React-Native is also attempting to connect to the emulator.

**Terminate The Connections:**

1. Leave the emulator running.
2. Close out of and uninstall any Android Studio/Eclipse Apps you have on the emulator. *This terminates apps trying to connect.*
3. Close Eclipse or Android Studio if either are running. Android Studio doesn't have to be open in order for the emulator to work **(This is important)**. *This terminates software trying to connect.*

After doing so I went back into my React-Native App and connected to Expo no problem.

**All you have to do is terminate all connections. However you so choose.**

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same error, it worked simply after restarting the AS on windows, of course, it asked for SDK update.

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio 4.1.3 with API 30 installation has this error
01-04-2021
**09:56 'C:\Users\ranja\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary**

Tried C:\Users\ranja>adb start-server

- daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
  **could not read ok from ADB Server
- failed to start daemon
  error: cannot connect to daemon**

Note: I have added 'C:\Users\ranja\Android\Sdk\platform-tools' in %PATH% environment variable on Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

i've encountered same error in my ionic 2. i just uninstall and reinstall ionic. and it works fine again..

```
npm uninstall -g ionic
npm install -g ionic
```