# Trouble running a program in Android Studio due to APK error.

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-emulator, apk

It's weird, I was using Android Studio fine and was able to run a project on an emulator. But after creating a new project a couple days ago, I haven't been able to run anything else since. I keep getting the error in the image below. I have looked online for a solution, but I haven't found any. I manually tried installing in the sdk in the sdk manager tool. I even ended up uninstalling the entire Android Studio and reinstalled it. I tried running a basic hello world app, and I still get the same error below. Any ideas?

[image: Screenshot of apk error.]

Comment: Which mobile device are you using?

Comment: It's not Android Studio issue

Comment: Did you read the entire message? It tells you exactly what to do.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yes I did read everything and tried figuring out  how to uninstall the apk. But it does make any sense, since the apk file is the app file that usually is used to install the app within the emulator. And brand new projects shows the same message. Unless I really don't know what the apk represent in this instance.

Comment: You are correct. The APK file is the main file for your app. The buttons should probably say "Yes" and "No" instead of "OK" and "Cancel". Clicking on OK will uninstall the current version and reinstall your app. What happens when you do this?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice when I click OK , I get an error in the console:
 "Session 'app': Error Installing APKs"

Comment: @Code-Apprentice , Okay I was able to solve the issue behind that error from this stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38450717/session-app-error-while-installing-apk    Where you have to turn off the instant run. That allowed installation of the apk onto my device.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Session 'app' error while installing APK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38450717/session-app-error-while-installing-apk)