# How to Fix Session 'app': Error Installing APK?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-install-apk

When I am trying to install the App on physical device, Android Studio throws me the error:

> Session 'app': Error Installing APK

About a week ago, it worked.
When I now try to install the APK again and again (about more than 20 times), sometimes it succeeds.

Even Eclipse can install the APK, but Android studio can't.

This question is my final way to find solution.
**I don't want re-install Android Studio**

**I m using Window 7, Galaxy Note 2 and 5**

Comment: I also recall seeing this error sporadically.  Sometimes, I think it happened because my USB cable wasn't completely connected.  Is this a very frequent problem for you?

Comment: i tried change the cable, but my cable is ok. cuz i installing Apk with eclipse and Android studio on same computer. and i can see the realtime mobile log on android studio

Comment: delete apk file from build -> output folder and try again. Also disable instant run. If still not work, try by restarting android studio.

Comment: Do not use Instant run, restart, and delete apk file are not work for me haha

Comment: did you try to install it on another device ? maybe an app with same package but different sign is already installed in this device. then previous build must be uninstalled.

Comment: yes i can test with more than 10 devices but every devices has same problem.. before installing, i delete app. but i got same problem.

Comment: I had the same issue disabling instant run solved the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Session 'app' error while installing APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38450717/session-app-error-while-installing-apk)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

- Disable the Instant run from File -> Settings -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Instant Run (uncheck it).
- Clean and Rebuild project.
- Try File -> Invalidate Cache & Restart
- Try removing the project from Android studio recent opened projects

Comment: Try invalidating cacehs and restart (File -> Invalidate Cache and Restart)

Comment: I also tried that too ;) now im trying to sync gradle and project.

Answer (score 0):

I tried invalidating the cache, clean/rebuild and it all failed. But I figured it out and depending on what you did to cause this, this may or may not be the answer.

Before the error appeared, I uninstalled the app on the testing phone, apparently, it isn't fully uninstalled. But rather it was deactivated. 
On Android Phone:

**Settings -> Apps -> Application List -> Select app in question**

Click the menu on the top right corner (it will say "**uninstall for all users**")

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem. this is how I solved the problem;

```
Android Studio > File > Sync Project with Gradle Files
```

or

```
Android Studio > Build > Rebuild Project
```

if they do not work, you must restart the device or emulator.