# Transferring Android Studio Project from Windows to MacOSX

Tags: macos, android-studio

So I have been working within Android Studio using a Windows Laptop, however I would like to transfer the Project over to my Macbook and keep working on it through there.The problem is when running the project on my Mac, Android Studio states,

"Application Installation"

"Failed Installation failed with message Invalid File"

"WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!"

so I click "OK" 
but my emulator won't run, and I'm left with just the project because this popup message prevents the emulator from running. Overall, this puts my Macbook in a useless state. Is there anyone who has had this problem by any chance and knows how to solve it?

Comment: did you try to just run your emulator from avd manager?

Comment: @KaranMer Hi, yes I used the Emulator within Android Studio, the Project appears to be fine my java and xml files also appear to be fine, the only problem is that when I test the app within the emulator, the emulator turns on but the popup comes up and the app doesn't even get to launch.

Comment: open avd manager and try downloading alternate system image. Also update emulator sdk tools.]

Comment: Hi, I updated my Android Studio and the problem not only continued but it included another problem which was actually solved in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38450717/session-app-error-while-installing-apk#comment76338480_42617107    Using this post, I was able to solve the new problem which also solved the original problem I had. Thank you very much for your help @KaranMer :)

Comment: Also, just incase anyone might have this problem, I had renamed a folder called "Android Dev" to just "Android" this folder just so happened to be located on my desktop where my Project was also located. I ended up renaming it back to "Android Dev", as I noticed that my issue arose after I had renamed it to "Android". I changed it back to "Android Dev" to ensure that Android Studio would not get confused as to where to locate my sdks, I doubt this caused an issue, but I was better safe than sorry. This along with the link above and @KaranMer help is what solved my issue. Thanks again.