# why when I try to install the application via USB there is an error , the error says : session 'app' did not installed , i used android studio 3.5

Tags: android, opencv, face-recognition

I want to install an APK via USB in android studio 3.5 but I get the following error: `Session 'app' did not installed.`

I also, try to install the APK via USB in my friend phone's, when I do this there are no issues or errors.

Why when I try to install APK via USB on my phone do I get an error?

My Build Gradle Code

```java
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe dup of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38450717/session-app-error-while-installing-apk

Comment: In my case updating ADB helped.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57702301/8034839

Comment: Some phone ask install permission during app install via usb. and it is counting 10. Before 10 second you have to allow to install otherwise you will get those error. (it will happen if the app not present in those mobile)

Comment: @ihsan.gaozp in android studio 3.5 there is no instant run in setting->Build,Execution,Deployment