# Android Studio app not launching, Android Emulator loads fine

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.0

after trying for around 3 hours I am unable to get just the default template app to work. To be specific the error I am having is:

```
14:58   Session 'app': Installation did not succeed.
            The application could not be installed.
            Installation failed due to: 'UNKNOWN'

            Retry
```

I have a AMD processor so I'm using HyperV and Hypervisor virtualization stuff and the device I am using is

480x800 hdpi display with Nougat Android 7.11 armeabi-v7a

Graphics is set to automatic, I found both had the same result.

Boot option is cold.

Ram: 512mb

VM heap 48mb

Internal storage 800mb

SD card 512mb

I've tried many of the things found on other peoples posts like Invalidate Caches/ restart.

This didn't work.

If you know how to help please share, thanks.

Edit: I tried changing the API level from 25 to 19, this returned a different `error: The application could not be installed: SHELL_UNRESPONSIVE`

I tried bumping up the available RAM and it stopped working returning the

```
Error while waiting for device: Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online.
```

I am really not sure how to actually make this work.

Comment: Did you try `clean`ing the project and then building it again? For more information look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38450717/session-app-error-while-installing-apk

Comment: Yes but it did not work